# Why can't I call my function when adding a parameter?

Tags: javascript, html

Can somebody tell me why when I put "3" for the parameter in function `a()` it doesn't work? Is that the wrong way?

[image: Function]

[image: function call]

Comment: pass like this "a('3')" , it will work

Comment: That's not valid JS code. Try `"a('3')"`

Comment: Don't post pictures of code. Those are absolutely useless. code is text. post the text here.

Comment: Mixing *three languages* on *one line of code* is just begging for quoting errors.

Comment: i cant put ' ' cause then 3 isnt in a string..  $znak=' <input type="button" onclick ="a('3')"  value="Zaključaj" >';

Comment: Sure you can, `'3'` and `"3"` are identical in javascript/html

Comment: @fvukovic so escape it...

Comment: but this is php...how?

Comment: php, outputting html and javascript. so you have to follow the rules of all three at once, or separate one from the other. *preferably the latter*

Comment: working..ty guys :D

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the same quotes to delimit the `onclick` attribute and the string inside it. Since you use double quotes around the attribute, you have to use single quotes around the argument. Since your PHP string is delimited with single quotes, you then need to escape the quote.

```
$znak = '<input type="button" onclick="a(\'3\')" value="Zaključaj">';
```

Another way is to use a here-string:

```
$znak = <<EOS
<input type="button" onclick="a('3')" value="Zaključaj">
EOS;
```